# monacaでfbのネイティブログイン認証をしたい

Tags: monaca, facebook

現在Monacaにてアプリ開発をしております。

Monacaで例えばPinterestのようなFBのネイティブログイン認証機能を組み込むことはできるのでしょうか？

アシアル公式ブログを参考にopenFBプラグインによるログイン認証を組み込んでみたのですが、こちらの方法だとwebViewによる認証方式となり、ユーザー側にID・パスワードの入力を求めることになり、これを回避したいと考えています。

追記
説明不足でした。
アプリのFacebookログインの実装なのですが、具体的に

・開発中アプリのログイン画面いてFBログイン用のボタンを押下
↓
・ユーザーの端末にFB公式アプリがDLされている場合、FB公式アプリへ移動
↓
・アプリを認証するかの確認画面にて、承認を実行
↓
・開発中アプリのログイン後の画面へ移動

というフローを実現したいと考えております。

Comment: phonegap-facebook-plugin(http://plugreg.com/plugin/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin)を利用することで解決いたしました。

Answer (score 1):

ネイティブログインと言うと
OSのシェア機能を使っての共有と言うことでしょうか？
端末にSNSシェア用のアプリがインストールされていれば、
iOS/Android両方対応可能だとは思います。

プランによっては実現不可能ですが、
CordovaPluginを使用しての実装になります。

既存のプラグインを使用するのであれば[コチラ](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)などですかね？

Comment: こちらも今後実装の予定ですが、相談の意図とは違います。ご回答ありがとうございました。